# Proof that the sum of a certain infinite series can be bounded to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\forall 0 < \alpha < 1$, there exists $\lambda > 0$, $k > 0$, s.t.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{w = 1}^{\lambda n} \binom{n}{w} \frac{1}{2^{\alpha n}}\left(1 +\left(1 - \frac{k\log{n}}{n}\right)^w\right)^{\alpha n} = 0.$$

Can someone give me hint on how to prove this? This is empirically true, and since $\lambda$ can be arbitrarily small, it is quite intuitive that this sum can be driven to $0$.

Comment: May I ask how did you encounter this problem?

Comment: In the proof that a parity check matrix in GF(2) requires O(log(n)) ones in each row to have good performance

Comment: It is actually quite easy to prove that if we only sum on $\forall p \sum_{w=pn}^{\lambda n}$ and for constant $W_0$, $\sum_{w=1}^{W_0}$, the proposition holds. But combining them is quite a challenge. We may even show that $\forall p \sum_{w=plogn}^{\lambda n}$ this holds, but there is always this gap that cannot be filled between constant and some $g(n)$ that grows to $\infty$ with n